# AngularJS - What is wrong with this directive I want to call on load

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have created a directive because I want to do some DOM manipulation when page loads. But it simply won't trigger. Here is my directive function:
**Directive**

```
function onLoadFixes(){
    return function (scope,element,attrs){
        $(element).on('load',function(event){
                console.log("element loaded");
                $(".breadcrumb-igdm").append($("#idBreadcrumbs").children());
                $("input").val(copyURLtoClipboard());
        });}
}
```

**This is how it is mapped**

```
.directive("uponLoadFixes", onLoadFixes)
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="header" ng-include="'partials/header.html'">
</header>
<div id="idBreadcrumbs" ng-show="false">
    <li class="active">{{phase.title}}</li>
</div>
<div role="main" style="margin-top:110px">
    <a role="button" href="javascript:;" ng-model="collapsedMap" ng-click="collapsedMap=!collapsedMap">
        <h4 style="color: #7D0DD0;">PROJECT PHASE {{phase.title}}</h4>
    </a>
    <div id="divMap" style="border: 1px solid grey;width: 98%;border-radius: 4px;padding:3px">
    <upon-load-fixes></upon-load-fixes>
        <table ng-show="collapsedMap" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="stream in streams|myMapFilter:'order'" style="height: 30px">
                    <td ng-style="{'width':'20%','padding-top':'1px'}" class="phase-stream-column-div">
                        <div ng-style="{'background-color':stream.color,'margin-top':'2px'}" class="content-center-flex">
                            {{stream.title}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="phase-stream-column-div" style="padding-left: 2px !important;padding-top:2px !important">
                        <div ng-style="{'background-color':stream.color,'cursor':'pointer'}" ng-repeat="stage in stages(stream.ukey).stages" ui-sref="stage" ng-click="openStage(stage)" class="content-center-flex">
                            {{stage.title}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any pointers are welcome.

**Header.html**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <table class="table" style="width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0px;background-color: white" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(192, 192, 192)">
                <td style="width: 10.0%;"><img alt="" src="img/iGDM_119_50.jpg"></td>
                <td style="background-color: rgb(0, 64, 128)"><span style="text-align: left;vertical-align: "><span
                style="nowrap: nowrap; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16pt"
            >Page Name</span> </span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10.0%;"><img alt="" src="img/hcl_logo_50.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="height: 30px;background-color: #f5f5f5;border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
        <ol class="breadcrumb pull-left breadcrumb-igdm">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="font-weight: 16px"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Waterfall</a></li>
            <upon-load-fixes></upon-load-fixes>
        </ol>
        <ul class="list-inline pull-right breadcrumb">

            <li ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#copyurl">
            <input type="text" id="copyurl" value=""><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-link" style="font-weight: 16px"></i>&nbsp;Copy URL</a></li>
            <li ng-click="open()"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="font-weight: 16px"></i>&nbsp;Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="font-weight: 16px"></i>&nbsp;Help</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

**New Directive**

```
( function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    var uponLoadFixes = function() {
        function controller() {

        }

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("doing something " + copyURLtoClipboard());
            element.append(angular.element(document.querySelector("#idBreadcrumbs")).children());
            angular.element(document.querySelector("#copyurl")).val(copyURLtoClipboard()); // get this function into the directive as well or make it a service

        }

        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            link : link,
            controller : controller,
            scope : {}
        };
    };

    angular.module('myMappy').directive('uponLoadFixes', [ uponLoadFixes ]);
})(angular);
```

Comment: This is incredibly un-angulary.  You should reconsider your approach.

Comment: Sorry. My second week with Angular. I have different JS files for directives/filters/services/factory and main app.js. So it looks pretty un-angular.

Comment: First of all, this is not the way Angular should be used. What do you expect to happen. Second you just return a function...it does what you tell it to do. Returning a function...Maybe you are looking for the `link` function?

Comment: @Arun understandable.  However, trying to mix your old bag of tricks into a new angular codebase is only going to cause you pain and misery.  You should be using directives for all of your DOM modifications, not jQuery.  Not to mention that subscribing the element on load event makes little to no sense in this case

Comment: I tried it with angular.element(). I can rid of input value setting and get that from my controller but I need to add breadcrumbs based on which page I am. I thought of using ng-repeat and an array but that proved to be more advanced for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to use load event in angularjs,

here is an example, you should try to follow,

```
(function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        var uponLoadFixes = function () {
            function controller() {

            }

            function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                //here do something
                var $$breadcrumb = element.find('.breadcrumb-igdm'); //try to fin the element with angularjs
                $$breadcrumb.append($("#idBreadcrumbs").children());
                $("input").val(copyURLtoClipboard());  //get this function into the directive as well or make it a service
            }

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: link,
                controller: controller,
                scope: {}
            };
        };

        angular.module('')
                .directive('uponLoadFixes', [uponLoadFixes]);
    })(angular);
```

Comment: Thanks. But same issue. It does not seem to trigger. I put a log message in link function and nothing on console. This is what is puzzling me.

Comment: yes but in your html, where you put the directive, there is no such a class called breadcrum-..., is that whole html you are using?

Comment: this class is in header which I am loading from a different template using ng-include. Problem is I added a console.log("helllo") in link function and it is not triggered as well.

Comment: you have onloadFixes & uponLoadFixes.  maybe make sure they are all same name.

Comment: Those are. Can you give me any simple example of such directive? I'll try to build on top of that.

Comment: edited HTML above to show complete picture. Adding "upon-load-fixes" as element is running the code now. I am trying to figure out the DOM Manipulation I need.

Answer (score 0):

**Run Blocks**
Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the services have been configured and the injector has been created.

```
  angular.module('myModule', []).      
    run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
      // This is an example of a run block.
      // You can have as many of these as you want.
      // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
      // into run blocks
    });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Thx. But would it run every time I navigate to a different page? I am using ui.router.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to z.a**. By moving my directive to breadcrumb list in header.html and using it as an element, it started working as expected (need to fix the display though). I have included the modified code for the directive (for element selection) should anyone is looking for it.